# Кнопка появляется после нажатия другой кнопки

Tags: python

У меня есть кнопка, по нажатии которой происходит команда. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при выполнении команды старая кнопка уничтожалась, а на ее месте появлялась новая.

```py
def press():
    btn.destroy()
    btn1 = ttk.Button(text="Кнопка", width=20)
    btn1.pack()
```

Код для понимания, он не рабочий. После нажатия кнопки она уничтожается, но на ее месте не появляется новая почему-то. Как решить?

Answer (score 0):

Обновите графич. интерфейс после создания новой кнопки. В этом поможет метод `update()` главного окна:

```
def press():
    btn.destroy()
    btn1 = ttk.Button(text="Кнопка", width=20)
    btn1.pack()
    root.update()
```

Comment: У меня не работает